# How to have an unordered_multimap of unordered_multimaps

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-multimap

I was practicing through unordered_multimaps and I came across a problem of having an unordered_multimap containing another unordered_multimap.The compiler throws an error saying c++ standard does not provide hash of this type.I guess I have to write a hash function but my understanding is limited since I am new to STL.

I have already tried something like inserting a struct or another multimap to the unordered_multimap but no luck so far.

```
std::unordered_multimap<long,long>m_Map1;
std::unordered_multimap<CString,m_Map1>m_Map2;    //This line throws 
error
//inserting to the map
m_Map1.insert(std::pair<long,long>(10,20));
m_Map2.insert(_T("ABC"),m_Map1);
//also the compiler does not let me create an object for this map
m_Map1 m_ObjMap;    //error here as well
```

How should I implement this.What I am trying to achieve here is one person's Name associated with birthdate and date on which he dies.I was hoping of having the dates in one map and mapping it with name to the m_Map2.

Comment: `m_Map1` isn't a type, but an instance of `std::unordered_multimap<long,long>` hende you get a compiler error. What you probably want is `std::unordered_multimap<CString,std::unordered_multimap<long,long>>m_Map2;`

Comment: In the declaration in your second multimap, you have to write something like `std::unordered_multimap<CString,std::unordered_multimap<long,long>>m_Map2`, not writing the name of your first multimap in the template.

Comment: Also, the last line is also wrong, `m_Map1` is already an object, hence you can not create a new object. I think you are messing up with types and objects here.

Comment: You are correct. The C++ standard does not define a hash on the non-standard `CString` type. Try using a standard `std::string`, and forget all about that non-standard class that only exists in the Microsoftverse.

Comment: You might have wanted to write something like `using Map1 = std::unordered_multimap<long, long>; std::unordered_multimap<CString,Map1> m_Map2;`

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ ..Thanks it compiles now but how do I insert the m_Map1 values to the m_Map2?

Comment: @Ventu..Thanks a lot for the help.I could successfully compile the code.But I am really not sure how to insert elements to it.I am doing something like....  
    m_Map1.insert(std::pair<long,long>(10,20));
    m_Map2.insert(std::pair<CString,std::pair<long,long>>(_T("A"),(m_Map1- 
    >first,m_Map1->second));
    //It says expression must have a pointer type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no specialisation of `std::hash` available for `CString`

Boiling the problem down to its simplest part, this will also not compile:

```
std::unordered_multimap<CString , int> m_Map2;
```

Because `std::unordered_multimap<CString, anything>` requires that there exists a class `std::hash<CString>` which provides `std::size_t operator()(CString const&) const` (it also requires an implementation of `std::equal_to<CString>` but this is automatically available if `CString` supports `operator==`.

You can create such a class and legally inject it into the std namespace:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>  // for boost::hash_range, see below

// for exposition
struct CString
{
    const char* data() const;
    std::size_t length() const;

    bool operator==(CString const& other) const;
};

namespace std
{
    // specialise std::hash for type ::CString
    template<> struct hash<::CString>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(CString const& arg) const
        {
            std::size_t seed = 0;

            // perform whatever is your hashing function on arg here
            // accumulating the hash into the variable seed
            // in this case, we're doing it in terms of boost::hash_range

            auto first = arg.data();
            auto last = first + arg.length();
            boost::hash_range(seed, first, last);

            return seed;
        }
    };
}

std::unordered_multimap<CString , int> m_Map2;
```

Comment: @RichardHodges..Thanks a lot but I am afraid I cant use boost at my place.But your answer has made me understand the problem in a better way.

Comment: @Somil great. Working as intended.